# How did Vo have a child?

Tags: cosmere, warbreaker

According to [this](https://www.coppermind.net/wiki/Vo) article from the Coppermind, Returned can have children, but require special knowledge to do so. The only known Returned to do so was Vo, the first Returned. The problem is, Vo was the first Returned so nobody could have taught him how to have a child and he only lived for a week, so how did he have a child?

Comment: Making a child doesn't take al that much time ;) BTW he had "visions" maybe one of them enlightened him how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 3):

### RAFO: we won't know till the sequel

If you follow the reference in the coppermind page you will go to the annotation by Sanderson.

> It is possible for a Returned to have a child. Vo, the First Returned, did it. The God King isn’t special in that he can do it; any of the Returned could, but ***it requires some special knowledge that—I’m afraid—I’ll have to keep secret until the sequel***. Suffice it to say that the priests know how it is done.
>
> *Annotation Warbreaker Chapter Forty-Four*

So we don't know the method, we will know in the future. As to how did Vo found out (since there was not priesthood then), we can surely speculate he found out the old way, by trying. Without the years of indoctrination by the priest the Returned hold they would have no pre-conception against trying having a child, aquiring more breaths and so on.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question because vo only had a week but he wouldnt have known that because he was the first

Comment: @Antheloth To be fair, I don't think we know much about what Vo did and did not know.  Endowment seems to intervene when sending a returned back.  He may have been sent back with some of that knowledge so that Endowment could accomplish whatever is being worked on.